# default css file for directory

Tags: css, .htaccess

Is there a way to apply a css file to all pages in a directory? I want to be able to create a simple html file, and a default css file will be applied to the page even though I did not specify that I wanted any stylesheet in my html file. I am assuming this would be done with the .htaccess file, but I am open to other methods.

Comment: htaccess cannot insert any code in your HTML source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't possible I would suggest looking into templating with php if your really looking for a easier way to not have to repeat adding the stylesheets heres a good getting started resource for php templating

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/getting-started-with-php-templating/

Also here's a explanation of what you can do with `.htaccess`

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files--net-4757